# Removing .html extension via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do you remove a .html extension or any extension using an .htaccess file?

Answer (score 3):

Google is your friend :-)

Take a look at [this article](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/).

Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Credit: http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/

Comment: Agreed - just make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled and the above snipped should do what you need.